# Custom Routes Access Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I have this in my routes.rb

```
  scope constraints: lambda { |r| r.env['warden'].user.nil? } do
    get "login", to: "sessions#new", as: "login"
  end
```

I tried accessing these on rspec by get "get 'signup'" but it does not work.

spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "/sessions/new" do
    it "will render if user is not yet logged in" do
        get :new
        response.response_code.should eq 200
    end

    it "will not render if user is logged in" do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        request.env['warden'].set_user(user)
        get "login"
        response.response_code.should eq 404
    end
end
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Failure/Error: get "login"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"login"}
```

Comment: So, what's the error message?

Comment: That's not enough information to figure out the problem. Please provide your spec code and the error message.

Comment: @BenjaminSullivan. I edited my question. I hope it's clearer now the problem.

Comment: @Wukerplank There I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb is meant for testing your SessionsController. `signup` is an action in the UsersController. Test the `signup` action in spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb.

Comment: That does not have something to do with the question that I asked but you're right. I edited the question because of your comment.

Comment: It would help if your question actually contained a question :)